Getting ApplicationVersion in azure pipeline yaml from .csproj file adds trailing spaces
In the Azure DevOps build pipeline for our .NET Maui app I need to get the version strings from the project file.
I moved the version info to the top of my project file, so it looks like this:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationDisplayVersion>2.0.1</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
...

Now I can read the version strings as XML with a PowerShell task:
    - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: Get version info from MauiProject.csproj
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $filePath = "MauiProject/MauiProject.csproj"
          [xml]$projectXml = Get-Content $filePath
          $ApplicationDisplayVersion = $projectXml.Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationDisplayVersion
          $ApplicationVersion = $projectXml.Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationVersion
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ApplicationDisplayVersion]$ApplicationDisplayVersion"
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ApplicationVersion]$ApplicationVersion"

The strange thing is that some spaces are attached to the version strings.
When I create a path with $(ApplicationDisplayVersion).$(ApplicationVersion) I get
...AppPackages/MauiProject_2.0.1     .1     _Windows...
instead of:
...AppPackages/MauiProject_2.0.1.1_Windows...
I tried to remove the spaces with PowerShell with -replace '\s','' but that did not help.
Questions:

Where do those spaces come from?
How can I remove them from the yaml variables?


Did you confirm that it's not a different whitespace character, like tabs?

From the PowerShell task definition, the  generated Pipeline variable should not contain spaces or tabs.  I tested the same powershell script and it can output the variable: 2.0.1.1 (no spaces) Can you share your script to create the Path? And you can check if it contains additional tabs or spaces in the create path script. On the other hand, you can also try to directly echo output the two variables and check if it indeed contains additional spaces.

@KevinLu-MSFT it looks like powershell Write-Host adds some spaces. When I run on the commandline Write-Host _($projectXml.Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationDisplayVersion)_ the result is _ 2.0.1  _

@KevinLu-MSFT When I define pipeline variables ApplicationDisplayVersion: '2.0.1' and    ApplicationVersion: '1' instead of the PowerShell script the path is correct ...AppPackages/MauiProject_2.0.1.1_Windows...

@MarcelWolterbeek When I try to use the similar write-host command to output the value, I can also see the unexpected space. To solve this issue, you can try to use the following format: Write-Host _$($projectXml.Project.PropertyGroup.ApplicationDisplayVersion)_
